# Performance in query, the query at server private, execute in 30 seconds , but same query execute in 12 minutes at azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, cloud

Performance in query, the query at server private, execute in 30 seconds , but same query execute in 12 minutes at azure
Azure Database S3 
The query uses 4 temporary table

Comment: **what is the query?**, My guess would be the use of temp tables on a cloud solution like Azure in that it stores the temp tables in memory with other people's stuff on the same server. Your private server has only your code to worry about so it's amount of memory to search is less.

Comment: I would not be surprised if your private server has far more resources (RAM and VPU) than the Azure one but it can be only a guess without further details that will exclude un-optimized operations during the execution.
Are you able to perform an EXPLAIN on both local server and Azure and post the results ?

Comment: For starters, upload the actual execution plans [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question.